# AutoCADのスライド・ファイルをC#で利用したい

Tags: c#, .net, ijcad

IJCAD 2015でC#（.Net API）を使って開発をしています。

AutoCADのDCLで表示するスライド・ファイルをC#でダイアログ上に表示させてみたいのですが、IJCADでやり方がわかれば教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

残念ながら、IJCADのC#ではSlideFileを表示することはできません。

AutoCADでもサポートしていないので、将来的にも期待できないです。